# Ideal way to load Excel data from Azure Data Lake to Azure SQL

Tags: sql-server, excel, azure, ssis

The source data is excel (**so already not starting off well, and they will not change to .csv, plus the source is a formatted report not a data feed**).

The client **does not have** any existing SQL Servers/SSISServers, so Azure SQL is what we have defined for them.

Client has tight control to not providing access to the Hyperion system (where the excel is sourced).

We need to move the data to Azure SQL.  Ideally I would of like to use Data Lake to store the csv files, but for now we are moving the excel to Data Lake.

Since **ADF does not support Excel**, we are forced to run SSIS.  Since Client does not have a SQL Server to have SSIS deployed, **how can I use SSIS Engine Runtime without a SQL Server to deploy?**

Also since the excel file is in Data Lake, I am not able to define the path to the ADL from ssis.  **How do define the Excel file path in SSIS pointing to Azure Data Lake**

Was wondering if anyone has faced this type of Use Case.

Comment: This feels better suited for research over on https://superuser.com/ or perhaps even https://dba.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I'm in the process of doing something very similar. My gameplan is to spin up an Azure VM that will run DTExec. I haven't gotten to the actual implementation phase yet, though, so I don't have more details right now.

Comment: Using azure data lake : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/integration-services/data-flow/azure-data-lake-store-source?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: Ssis with azure sql database without sql serve on promises : https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/sql/integration-services/lift-shift/ssis-azure-deploy-run-monitor-tutorial?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: ADF supports excel now.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can see this Azure reference:[Import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017). This article describes the connection information that you have to provide, and the settings that you have to configure, to import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS).

**Specify Excel as your data source** :

**In SSIS**:

1. In SSIS, create an Excel Connection Manager to connect to the Excel source or destination file. There are several ways to create the connection manager:
2. In the Connection Managers area, right-click and select New connection. In the Add SSIS Connection Manager dialog box, select EXCEL and then Add.On the SSIS menu, select New connection. In the Add SSIS Connection Manager dialog box, select EXCEL and then Add.
3. Create the connection manager at the same time that you configure the Excel Source or the Excel Destination on the Connection manager page of the Excel Source Editor or of the Excel Destination Editor.

**Excel file and file path**

The first piece of info to provide is the path and file name for the Excel file. You provide this info in the Excel Connection Manager Editor in an SSIS package, or on the Choose a Data Source or Choose a Destination page of the Import and Export Wizard.

Enter the path and file name in the following format:

1. For a file on the local computer, C:\TestData.xlsx.
2. For a file on a network share, \Sales\Data\TestData.xlsx.

I haven't faced this type of Use case for now. Hope this can be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

ADF, Azure Data Factory now supports Excel, but it did not when you asked your question.

"Excel format is supported for the following connectors: Amazon S3, Azure Blob, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen1, Azure Data Lake Storage Gen2, Azure File Storage, File System, FTP, Google Cloud Storage, HDFS, HTTP, and SFTP. It is supported as source but not sink."

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/format-excel